# Redirect non-https tcp streams on 443 in apache to another application

Tags: apache-httpd, nginx, connection-sharing

I cannot find any Apache mod that allows something like IIS on Windows allows - You can run an SSTP VPN server on port 443 and a HTTPS server on port 443 too at the same time, bound to the same interface. I was wondering if anything like that is possible with Apache? Or nginx? How would I configure such a thing?

If not possible, what are my options for running, for example OpenVPN, on TCP:443 along with a web server on 443? Or any other software on Linux based machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVPN seems to have the `--port-share` option

> **--port-share host port [dir]**
>    When run in TCP server mode, share the OpenVPN port with another application, such as an HTTPS server.  If OpenVPN senses a  connection  to  its  port
>                 which  is  using  a  non-OpenVPN  protocol, it will proxy the connection to the server at host:port.

If say the webserver was listening for HTTPS traffic on localhost:49152, then the openvpn config could contain:
`port-share localhost 49152`

Comment: oh nice! thanks to this info I also found `sslh` which seems to be a very useful program so I can do ssh on 443 too!